# Having trouble with dynamic casts c++

Tags: c++

I am trying to write a simple program, as a demonstration for casting back and forth between a base class object, and a derived class object.  Here is my code

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class a
{
    virtual void hi(){}
};

class b : public a
{
};

int main()
{
    a abs = b();
    b& bbs = dynamic_cast<b&>(abs);
    while(true);
}
```

The code compiles fine, however when i run it i get an "Unhandled exception at at 0x75C4C41F in Class Tests.exe: Microsoft C++ exception: std::bad_cast at memory location 0x003DF908."  I dont see what i am doing wrong.  Could anyone explain to me why this is not working.

Comment: `abs` is an `a`, not a `b`. So you can't `dynamic_cast` it to anything else.

Comment: Public base classes should be abstract; if you stick to this rule, such nonsense would never compile.

Comment: You hit the **slicing** problem ...

Comment: Re: "casting back and forth between a base class object, and a derived class object" - the code does **not** cast between object types; it casts **references to objects**. Don't muddle these two; if you do, the difference will bite you later.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this is probably what you were trying to do:

```
#include <iostream>

class a
{
    public:
        virtual void hi(){}
        virtual ~a() {}
};

class b : public a
{
};

int main()
{
    b b_obj;
    a& a_ref_to_b = b_obj;
    b& b_ref_to_b = dynamic_cast<b&>(a_ref_to_b);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 6):

You're running into a C++ problem called "slicing". Basically, `abs` is an `a`, not a `b`, because the statement

```
a abs = b();
```

1. Creates a new `b` object.
2. Looks for an `a` constructor that takes a `b`, and finds the copy constructor for `a` (based on the implicit conversion from `b` to `a`).
3. Converts the new `b` object to an `a` (by discarding the part specific to `b`) and passes it to the copy constructor for `a`.

If you need to copy objects polymorphically (which may or may not be what you actually need in your real code), the typical way to do so is to do something like this:

```
class a
{
public:
    virtual a *clone() { return new a(*this); }
};

class b
{
    virtual a *clone() { return new b(*this); }
};

b my_b;
a *abs = my_b.clone();
```

Again, not sure if that's what you need in this case, but there it is.

Answer (score 3):

Your code has an error. `abs` is an object of type `a`, and was copy constructed from an anonymous instance of `b`. What you need is an instance of a `b` and make `abs` a reference to `a`.

```
b bbs;
a &abs = bbs;
b &bbr = dynamic_cast<b&>(abs);
```

You should have a virtual destructor defined in `a` since you want to use polymorphism (although it is not required for this example).

Answer (score 1):

you can't dynamic cast an object. You only can cast a reference or a pointer.

change it to

```
a* abs = new b();
b* bbs = dynamic_cast<b*>(abs);
```

or

```
b obj_b = b();
a& abs = obj_b;
b& bbs = dynamic_cast<b&>(abs);
```

Comment: it depends. just make sure it won't be a [dangling pointer](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dangling_pointer)